# Applescript opening wrong version of OS X app

Tags: applescript

My script is opening an old version of the app (which I wrote). I have searched the HD and cannot find the old app. The new version is in the applications folder. The script is in the scripts folder.

I made a new folder and put the script and the new app in it. Running the script still opens the wrong app. App2 is the problem child.

Where is the wrong path coming from?

How to:

Point the script at the correct app? I don't want a path in the script.

Find the old app and delete it?

```
property checkInterval : 5 -- Number of seconds between checks. Adjust to requirement.
global App1WasOpen, GUIScriptingWasEnabled, previousText

on run
 -- When the script starts up, note if App1 is running and GUI Scripting is enabled.
 tell application "App1" to activate
 tell application "System Events"
   set App1WasOpen to (application process "App1" exists)
   set GUIScriptingWasEnabled to (UI elements enabled)
 end tell

 -- Enable GUI Scripting if nec. and give the 'previousText' variable an initial value.
 switchGUIScripting(true)
 set previousText to ""
end run

on idle
-- Each time the script's polled by the system, check that App1's open.
tell application "System Events" to set App1IsOpen to (application process "App1" exists)

if (App1gIsOpen) then
  set App1WasOpen to true
  -- Get the latest value for 'beam'.
  tell application "App1"
       set hdg to getHeading
       set beam to hdg as string
   end tell
   if ((count beam) < 3) then set beam to text -3 thru -1 of ("000" & beam)

   -- If it's changed since the last check, enter it into App2 and keep it for later checks.
   if (beam is not previousText) then
       --display dialog "Opening App2" buttons {"OK"}
       tell application "App2" to launch
       --activate application "App2"
       tell application "System Events"

           set startTime to current date
           repeat until exists (text field 1 of window "App2" of application process "App2")
               if (current date) - startTime is greater than 5 then
                   error "Could not find text field 1 of window AppB of application process App2"
                   exit repeat
               end if
               delay 0.2
           end repeat
           tell application process "App2"
               try
                   set value of text field 1 of window "App2" to beam
               end try
           end tell
       end tell
       --tell application "App1" to activate
       set previousText to beam
   end if
   -- Request the next 'idle' event in 'checkInterval' seconds' time.
     return checkInterval
   else if (App1WasOpen) then
   -- App1 was open at the last check, but isn't now. Tell this script applet to quit.
   quit
   -- It'll actually quit on the next idle event, so request a short interval.
   return 1
 end if
end idle

-- Unless GUI Scripting was already on when the script started to run, turn it on or off as per the parameter.
on switchGUIScripting(onOff) -- 'onOff' is 'true' for on, 'false' for off.
if (not GUIScriptingWasEnabled) then
   tell application "System Events"
       activate
       set UI elements enabled to (onOff)
   end tell
end if
end switchGUIScripting

-- When this applet's told to quit, restore the previous GUI Scripting state before it does.
on quit
   switchGUIScripting(false)
   continue quit
end quit
```

Followup:
I used "Show in Finder" on the app's icon in the dock to point me to 17 Xcode archives, which I deleted. Now the script has a recurring message of "An error of type -10660 has occurred", and App2 never opens.

I opened the script editor, copied the code to a new script window and compiled it with a different name. Still doesn't open App2.

Comment: Have you tried `mdfind -name App2`?

Comment: Interesting - That finds a couple in the Xcode output .dsyms and one in sent email, but not in applications or documents. I'm going to edit the OP to tell what's been done and the results.

Answer (score 0):

Try finding the Applications id with:

```
set appID to get id of application "/Applications/Safari.app"
```

Once you have found it, refer to the id rather than

```
tell application id "com.apple.Safari" to launch
```